# Codeigniter show results of database query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to display some testimonials of my database, but after 2 days trying different code combinations I have to give up and hope that someone here knows better than me :)

Here is what I have so far:

model:

```
    function getTestimonials() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('feedback_comments');   
    $c = $this->db->get();
    return $c;
    }
```

controller:

```
    $testimonials = $this->feedback_model->getTestimonials();
    $this->outputData['testimonials'] = $testimonials;
```

and finally the view:

```
    <?php $i = 1; foreach($testimonials as $testimonial) { ?>
    <?php echo $testimonial->dated; ?>, <?php echo $testimonial->comment; ?>
    <?php } ?>
```

For some reason, the results are not being displayed. It does not show any errors, but it does show 7 lines with two commas in each line, which is strange since the BD only has one record.

Any clue on what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What does `var_dump($this->feedback_model->getTestimonials())` show?

Comment: Where's the code in which you load your view?

Comment: PS: You can shorten your `getTestimonials` method to one line, by doing: `function getTestimonials(){ return $this->db->get('feedback_comments'); }`

Comment: @RainFromHeaven, your line shows: object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#47 (7) { ["conn_id"]=> resource(39) of type (mysql link persistent) ["result_id"]=> resource(70) of type (mysql result) ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(1) ["row_data"]=> NULL }

Comment: the answers below are all good. now consider - what happens if there are no results back from the database? you want your application to be able to deal with that contingency. so in your model method, check if there are results, and if not, have it return false. Then in your controller you can IF check whether it returned results. if there are no results, then you won't try and pass it to the view, maybe you create a no results message to show, maybe you show a different view thats appropriate for no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may want to have a look at this: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

The problem is quite simple, you're not storing your results into anything. Basically, you need to change :

```
return $c;
```

Into:

```
return $c->result();
```

Why do you need to make the change above? Basically whenever you're running the get() method, you're retrieving a connection to a DB query, which allows you to check the number of rows, specifics about the connection type, etc. If you want to gain access to the results, just call the result() method (or result_array if you prefer) on the connection string.

Comment: Thanks, this did it. Great solution, thank you all for your help and ideas! I really appreciate it! ;)

Comment: @Ben Cool mate, great to hear it worked nicely!:) As some of the other comments/answers have noted, try using var_dump() whenever you're unsure about what a variable holds, or go one step beyond that and use a dedicated tool such as XDebug to inspect your calls.

Comment: thanks for this advise, will have a look at it and use it in the future, its always good to learn more about resolving errors :) Again, thanks so much for all the answers here, you guys rocK!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your Model code with this one.

```
 function getTestimonials() {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('feedback_comments');   
    $c = $this->db->result();
    return $c;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just this for the model method:

```
function getTestimonials() {
    return $this->db->get('feedback_comments')->result();
}
```

However, you're not showing how are you loading your view. This line: `$this->outputData['testimonials'] = $testimonials;` looks a bit non-standard (because you used $this, but it should work). This is the basic concept of loading a view:

```
$outputData['testimonials'] = $testimonials;
$this->load->view('my_view', $outputData);
```

Comment: thats a great point, and i would go further and say please use $data['testimonials'] because passing $data to the view is the standard.